# Schemaless Elasticsearch not analyzed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to index documents dynamically, thus I am using schemaless mapping for elasticsearch.

But when i search for an exact match for a value like "ABC XYZ" against a string field, I do not get any hits.

Also I need my search to be case insensitive. Is it possible to acheive this, only by making changes while search like by specifying an analyzer.

I am new to elasticsearch so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("fieldName", "ABC XYZ");
```